# SAS join on a flag to indicate percentile

Tags: sas, left-join, sas-macro, percentile, do-loops

I am looking to join two tables together

Table 1 - The baseball dataset

```
DATA baseball;
    SET sashelp.baseball
        (KEEP = crhits);
RUN;
```

Table 2 - A table containing the percentiles of CRhits

```
PROC STDIZE 
    DATA = baseball
    OUT=_NULL_      
    PCTLMTD=ORD_STAT
    PCTLDEF=5
    OUTSTAT=STDLONGPCTLS
        (WHERE = (SUBSTR(_TYPE_,1,1) = "P"))
    pctlpts = 1 TO 99 BY 1;
RUN;
```

I would like to join these tables together to create a table that contains the values for crhits and then a column identifying which percentile that value belongs to like below

```
crhits    percentile    percentile_value
54        p3            54
66        p5            66
825       p63           825
1134      p76           1133
```

The last column indicates the percentile value given by stdlongpctls

I currently use the following code to calculate the percentiles and a loop to count the number of "Events" per percentile, per factor

I have tried a cross-join but I am having trouble visualising how to join these two tables without an explicit key

```
PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE cross_join_table   AS
    SELECT
          a.crhits
        , b._TYPE_
        , CASE WHEN
            a.crhits < b.type       THEN b._TYPE_   END AS percentile
    FROM
        baseball                    a
    CROSS JOIN
        stdlongpctls                b;
QUIT;
```

If there is another easier / more efficient way to find the number of observations and number of dependent variables (e.g. I am modelling on a default flag event in my actual dataset, so the sum of 1's per percentile group, I would appreciate it)

Answer (score 0):

Use PROC RANK instead to group it into the percentiles.

```
proc rank data=sashelp.baseball out=baseball_ranks group=100;
var crhits;
rank rank_crhits;
run;
```

You can then summarize it using PROC MEANS.

Comment: I was hoping to find a different way as I am running this analysis on over 500 variables. Proc rank calculates the percentiles incorrectly unless the data is sorted first where as proc stdize produces the percentiles for all variables at once, do you still recommend this method?

Comment: @78282219  'PROC RANK calculates the percentiles incorreclty unless the data is sorted first' I've never seen any indication of that. Can you provide an example or reference please?

Comment: I have used proc rank for over 500 variables to calculate the ranks of them all at once, I have seen that there are numbers not in ascending order according to their ranks; I can't show you with my dataset unfortunately

Comment: The numbers will not be in ascending order because each variable is done separately. If you can replicate it with a SASHELP data that would be helpful, but I'm fairly certain that doesn't happen. I don't know if you can get the PCTLDEF function but I'd argue that it likely doesn't matter for what you're doing at this scale. If it does, the alternative is to do this via macro or manually.  I did write a macro that automates this of sort so you can just provide the list. Ultimately, it needs to meet your reqs though. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/7cffd06ebc3bc9c78b4f6a5b4538b053

Comment: I'll check out your macro thank you, when I sorted the data in ascending order the values weren't monotonic

Comment: Show an example please. I genuinely don't see how that could ever occur.